# Python while loop inside while loop does not break

Tags: python, while-loop

This is a tic tac toe game. In this section the function checks if there is an unfilled cell on the board (first while loop, it works), then checks if o has won (the second while loop, it works).

If o won it breaks the loop and prints "yey o". The same for checking if x won, the third loop which also works except that when it breaks it prints "congrats x" to the infinity.

I tried adding a break statement on the level of the second loop  (as in " x won so break x, break o) but no success. What am I doing wrong?

```
def place_marker():
    while any(isinstance(x, int) for x in board):
        while not win_check_o():
            while not win_check_x():
                # does stuff
            else:
                print("congrats x")
                break
        else:
            print("yey o")
            break

    print(board)
```

Comment: I don't know your whole structure but something like `while not win_check_o() or  not win_check_x()` may be what you look as you need to check for both ending

Comment: Add `break` twice in innermost while loop and try.

Comment: @Prudhvi *break* leaves a loop, nothing after the break is reached _ever_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `break` statement only exits from its containing loop. If you have two nested loops and a `break` statement in the inner loop, you will go back to the outer loop.

```py
while True:
    while True:
        break
    print('This will repeat forever.')
```

To fix it, put your loops in a funciton and use a `return` statement instead.

Comment: I changed the functions checking if either x or o won to return True if nobody yet won (keep playing) or False if someone won. Then, I changed the main function to see below. The cheching part works perfectly, however, now it does not print the "congrats" lines. So, so close!

def place_marker():

    while any(isinstance(x, int) for x in board):
        if win_check_o is False:
            print('congrats o')
        if win_check_x is False:
            print('congrats x')
        if win_check_o() and win_check_x():

            # do stuff

Answer (score 2):

`break` only breaks from one loop. You should flatten your logic into one loop - you *could* make some booleans and tag them along to remember breaking out fully (very bad style):

```
a, SomeOtherCondition, thatCondition, SomeThing  = True, True, True, True

# contrieved bad example
while a and SomeOtherCondition:
    while a and thatCondition:
        while a and SomeThing:
            a = False
            print("Breaking")
            break
        # any code here will be executed once
        print("Ops") 
    # any code here will also be executed once
    print("Also ops")
```

Outputs:

```
Breaking
Ops
Also ops
```

---

It would be better to structure your code and flatten your loops:

## some helper methods

```
def any_tile_left(board):
    return any(isinstance(x, int) for x in board)  


def win_check(who, board):
    conditions = [(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8), # horizontal
                  (0,3,6),(1,4,7),(2,5,8), # vertical
                  (0,4,8),(2,4,6)]         # diagonal
    for c in conditions:
        if all(board[i] == who for i in c):
            return True
    return False


def print_board(board):
    for row in range(0,9,3):
        print(*board[row:row + 3], sep = "   ")
```

## game:

```
whos_turn = "X"
boardrange = range(1,10)
board = list(boardrange)

while True: 
    print_board(board) 
    try:
       pos = int(input(whos_turn + ": Choose a tile? "))
    except ValueError:
        print("impossible move. ", whos_turn,  "is disqualified and lost.")
        break

    if pos in boardrange and str(board[pos-1]) not in "XO":
        board[pos-1] = whos_turn
        if win_check(whos_turn, board):
            print(whos_turn, " won.")
            break
        whos_turn = "O" if whos_turn=="X" else "X"
    else:
        print("impossible move. ", whos_turn,  "is disqualified and lost.")
        break

    if not any_tile_left(board):
        print("Draw")
        break
```

It should work for a tic-tac-toe. Be careful to not input something thats impossible or you loose.